# What is 'Starting position out of bounds: -1'?

Tags: unit-test

After I run my test class, I got below message,

> Starting position out of bounds: -1.

What does it mean ? Because it doesn't show whether the test was succeeded or failed

Comment: please share code for test class/original class.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are zero-bounded. It's illegal to try to use a method on a string where the first index would be less than zero. For example, the following code causes this same error:

```
System.debug('Hello World'.substring(-1));
```

Your unit test failed, because you had an uncaught exception. Make sure you check your indices such that you do not try to access a character index less than zero or greater than or equal to String.length().

Comment: I am comming up with the same error from 'accountId = String.isBlank(accountId) ? currUrl.substring(currUrl.indexOf('001'),currUrl.indexOf('001')+15) : accountId;'line of code.Here currUrl='/apex/SAPcustomCommunityLoginPage'. Any idea on this?

Comment: @RuklaniAttanyake If there's no Id there, you'd get a similar error, yes. Consider using a Pattern/Matcher instead.

Answer (score -3):

May be your list have no values and you want to access the list ...
 so you have to use null check in class
if(!list.isEmpty() || list == null)

Comment: If `list` is null in the example you gave you will get an NPE. You need to switch the checks around to avoid NPEs